# How to extend init constructor

Tags: swift, constructor, extend, init

source code:

```
protocol UIImageExtension{

    init?(normalImage: NSInteger, pressedImage: String, textTag: NSInteger)

}


extension UIImageView: UIImageExtension{

    required convenience init?(normalImage: NSInteger, pressedImage: String, textTag: NSInteger)

    {

        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)

    }

}
```

I want to add a init methods like above, But it always not right,  Anyone can review source code and help me right from wrong? thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you just extend UIImageView itself, without implementing any protocols? Just adding a new convenience init function should work. Don't forget to add a self.init(..) in your convenience init so it can compile.

Comment: "But it always not right" : What do you mean?  What is not right?